# Access the next k elements in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, reinforcement-learning

I have a reinforcement learning game in which two agents interact with each other. I would now like to solve the following problem in Python.

I have created a `for-loop` that does something like this:

```
self.rewards_hist = []
self.number_episodes = 1000

def Game(self):
 
   for episode in range(self.number_episodes):

       doSomething()

       rewards = self.save_rewards()

       self.rewards_hist.append(rewards)
```

Thus, with `self.rewards` I get the reward at time `t` and in `self.rewards_hist` I receive the history of all rewards, hence giving me access to the previous rewards.

Now I want to compare this reward with the rewards in `t + k`, i.e. I would have to wait `k` episodes in the iteration until I can compare the current reward with the upcoming rewards. I am aware that within the `for-loop` this does not work because it is not possible to access the next rewards in the current iteration. Therefore I would need a function that allows me to wait for the next `k` rewards and only then make the comparison.

What is the easiest way to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  It's logically impossible to compare a result that you just computed with a result that you haven't computed yet.  You can't compare two results until you actually have both of them.  So why don't you just wait until t + k, and then start to compare new results with the old ones that you computed already?  There is no function that can magically see into the future.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am fully aware that the comparison within iteration does not work (as I also mentioned in the text above). My concern is actually exactly how I could implement to wait t+k episodes and then make the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already *have* a function that waits for the next k rewards: it's the function you have presented.  After k more steps in the iteration, you can compare the latest result (t+k) with the previous result (t).  Not before.  Let's rewrite your last paragraph:

"Now I want to compare this reward (at time t) with the *previous* reward at t - k, i.e. I have to look back k episodes in the iteration and compare the current reward with the previous reward. Since I have been storing each element as I compute it, this only requires accessing element self.rewards_hist[-k]. Therefore I already have all the information I need."

Of course it is true that an iterator cannot see elements that it hasn't computed yet.  How can it possibly be any other way?  The only solution is to compute those elements, and then compare them to the results that were computed in the past.  You can present this information to the end-user in any form you want; you could write a print statement that prints element[t] on the same line as element[t+k].  At the instant the print statement fires, your iterator is already at step t+k.  But the end user doesn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an actual counter for that:

```
counter = 0
for episode in range(self.number_episodes):
    doSomething()
    counter += 1
    if counter == k:
        counter = 0
        rewards = self.save_rewards()
        self.rewards_hist.append(rewards)
```

or nested loops:

```
for episode_batch in range(0, self.number_episodes-k+1, k):
    for episode in range(episode_batch, episode_batch+k):
        doSomething()
    rewards = self.save_rewards()
    self.rewards_hist.append(rewards)
```